# ElasticSearch Kibana bin folder doesn't have plugin.bat

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-marvel

I am trying to setup Elastisearch on my Windows 10 PC. Just downloaded the lastest version of Kibana (4.6.1) from the offical site:https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana

The strange thing is that under its bin folder, there is no plugin.bat  which i want to use for installing marvel according to this page: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/marvel

[image]

Did I follow the wrong way to install or something wrong with the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe plugin is an option to the kibana.bat. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-plugins.html). 
There is an example too. "bin/kibana plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest"